# JBoss EJB 3 issue DeploymentException

Tags: deployment, jboss, ejb-3.0

I am deploying a EJB3 Jar with several beans in it. The jar works fine on other instances and is deployed correctly. However if I try that on my machine, I get the DeploymentException.
I am on JBoss 5.1.0
Please help!!

Here is the stack trace:

---

*** DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR: Name -> Error

vfszip:/D:/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/Enhanced-QC-ejb.jar/ -> org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Error deploying: Factory$org.jboss.aspects.remoting.InvokeRemoteInterceptor

DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "vfszip:/D:/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/Enhanced-QC-ejb.jar/" is in error due to the following reason(s): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Factory$org.jboss.aspects.remoting.InvokeRemoteInterceptor is already installed.

```
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.checkComplete(DeployersImpl.java:993)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.checkComplete(DeployersImpl.java:939)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.checkComplete(MainDeployerImpl.java:873)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.checkComplete(MainDeployerAdapter.java:128)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.hotdeploy.HDScanner.scan(HDScanner.java:369)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.hotdeploy.HDScanner.run(HDScanner.java:255)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:317)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:150)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:181)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:205)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to clean the `tmp` directory (`D:/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/tmp` in your case) and restart JBoss.

Comment: Thanks.. It worked!
Having probs with Hibernate now... Will solve that now :)